# Как осуществить поиск всех файлов, соответствующих маске?

Tags: bash, linux

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Разработать программу, осуществляющую поиск всех файлов, соответствующих маске (поиск начинается с корневого каталога) и помещающих их список в файл. Маска и имя выходного файла передаются в программу через командную строку.

Comment: @Денис258, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 9):

```
find / -name "$1" > $2
```

Comment: А полностью можно?

Comment: Это полностью.

Comment: Это не просто полностью. Это **победа**.

Comment: Думаю, предполагалось, что задание должно научить пользоваться рекурсией.

Comment: А можно готовый код программы?

Comment: Кажется вам [сюда][1]


  [1]: http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/BOOKS/abs-guide/flat/abs-book.html